# WiFi request times out after ~5 mins

Tags: wireless-networking

I have this weird problem with my WiFi router. It stops working after a while. I have to switch it off and switch it back on to get it working temporarily.

```
ping 192.168.0.1
...
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=10928 ttl=64 time=3.592 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 10929
...
```

For some reason, it just times out like 5 min later. When I power it off and back on again, it works (reply).
Is my WiFi router dying ?

Comment: It looks like the router is in fact having a HW problem. There is a slim chance that there is a firmware issue, post brand and model, so we can look it up.

Comment: D-link Wireless Router DL-524.

Comment: Do you have a dsl modem as well? If so, the wireless modem and the Dsl one could have the same address (198.162.0.1) which is a problem. Change the default gateway of the D-link to 198.168.1.1 reboot and give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try another wireless device. If the second wireless device is experiencing the same problem with staying connected, I'd say its time to replace the router.

Do you have your wifi connected to a surge protector? For some reason wifi routers seem particularly prone to frying.

Comment: _I would try another wireless device._ My Mac was timing out, my mobile was showing WiFi error and my Ubuntu machine is not even showing the list of the WiFi devices. This was a sure problem with the router which I replaced with a brand new one after which everything started functioning normally. Thanks.